# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shapes.AddPicture Proportional Image Manipulation

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

Is there a way to add a picture that is proportionally constrained to a certain area?  I'm having to modify a program I wrote years ago, and the customer is supplying me with image sizes that are all over the place!  Worse, it seems like us manipulating the image on it's own.  I don't see anything in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shapes.addpicture?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_Shapes_AddPicture_System_String_System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__) that stand out for this, so here I am!  I realize that there are `.Height` and `.Width` object parameters, but given the current supply of images, I am hoping to avoid writing code that works this out.  I'm also hoping to avoid adding more libraries.  Worse comes to worse I can do this in ImageMagick, but even then theres still no explination for why a 300x300 image will consume 1/4 of a sheet.  The original image was 300x100 and fit in the header just fine.

```
          Try
            'Open the template
            objDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(appPath & "\PackListTemplate.dotm", [ReadOnly]:=True)
            'set word document as active
            objDoc = objWordApp.ActiveDocument

            Using conn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnStr)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    With objDoc
                        'get the image blob and store it as a file
                        'return the file path
                        Dim filePath As String = WriteImageFromDb()

                        'apply the filepath as the image header of the document
                        .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = 0
                        .Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddPicture(filePath)

                    End With
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Console.ReadLine()
        Finally

            'quit msWord
            objWordApp.Quit()

            'clear objWord object
            If Not objWordApp Is Nothing Then objWordApp = Nothing

            'close com objects on parent system
            If Not objDoc Is Nothing Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objDoc)
            End If

            If Not objWordApp Is Nothing Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWordApp)
            End If

            'If Not objTable Is Nothing Then objTable = Nothing
            If Not objDoc Is Nothing Then objDoc = Nothing
            If Not objWordApp Is Nothing Then objWordApp = Nothing
            'exit application with exit code 0 (successful)
            ' Environment.Exit(0)
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
```

**EDIT:**
I noticed in Intellisense that there is a `.WidthRelative` property.  Strange its not in the docs, but shouldnt be suprised.  I guess if I can get the image dimensions, I can work out what value to apply to it.

Comment: You can proportionally constrain an image by inserting it into a table cell with either the row height or the column width set to an "exact" measurement, if that helps...

Comment: For a VBA implementation using a table, see: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16772-4-digital-images-1-page.html#post47919

Comment: @CindyMeister that sounds logical, I might play around with that as well.  After all, the entire document is built off of a template, so that should work well too.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own post.  Hate doing this but I hope it helps someone else!  Given that I found the `.HeightRelative` and the `.WidthRelative` properties, I just did some math on the properties of the image and applied it to the header.  I didn't get the disired effect, it was inconsistent image to image, so I just went ahead an manipulated the `.Height` and `.Width` properties.  There may be an easier way to do it but this got me where I needed to be.

```
          Try
            'Open the template
            objDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(appPath & "\PackListTemplate.dotm", [ReadOnly]:=True)
            'set word document as active
            objDoc = objWordApp.ActiveDocument

            Using conn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnStr)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    With objDoc
                        'get the image blob and store it as a file
                        'return the file path
                        Dim filePath As String = WriteImageFromDb()
                                                    Dim filePath As String = WriteImageFromDb()
                        Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(filePath)
                        Dim imgX As Integer = img.Width
                        Dim imgXLim As Integer = 350
                        Dim imgY As Integer = img.Height
                        Dim imgYLim As Integer = 100
                        Dim imgXdiff As Integer = imgX - imgXLim
                        Dim imgYdiff As Integer = imgY - imgYLim
                        Dim growFactor As Double
                        Dim shrinkFactor As Double
                        .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = 0
                        With .Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes
                            'Check to see if the image is too big
                            If imgX > imgXLim Or imgY > imgYLim Then
                                If imgXdiff > imgYdiff Then
                                    shrinkFactor = (imgXLim / imgX) - ((imgXLim / imgX) Mod 0.1) 'Decimal Floor
                                ElseIf imgYdiff > imgXdiff Then
                                    shrinkFactor = (imgYLim / imgY) - ((imgYLim / imgY) Mod 0.1) 'Decimal Floor
                                End If
                                imgX = imgX * shrinkFactor
                                imgY = imgY * shrinkFactor
                                'If the image isn't too big, check to see if it's too small
                            ElseIf imgX < imgXLim Or imgY < imgYLim Then
                                If imgXdiff > imgYdiff Then
                                    growFactor = (imgXLim / imgX) - ((imgXLim Mod imgX) / imgX) ' Integer Floor
                                ElseIf imgYdiff > imgXdiff Then
                                    growFactor = (imgYLim / imgY) - ((imgYLim Mod imgY) / imgY) ' Integer Floor
                                End If
                                imgX = imgX * growFactor
                                imgY = imgY * growFactor
                            End If
                            With .AddPicture(filePath)
                                .Width = imgX
                                .Height = imgY
                            End With
                        End With
                    End With
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Console.ReadLine()
        Finally

            'quit msWord
            objWordApp.Quit()

            'clear objWord object
            If Not objWordApp Is Nothing Then objWordApp = Nothing

            'close com objects on parent system
            If Not objDoc Is Nothing Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objDoc)
            End If

            If Not objWordApp Is Nothing Then
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objWordApp)
            End If

            'If Not objTable Is Nothing Then objTable = Nothing
            If Not objDoc Is Nothing Then objDoc = Nothing
            If Not objWordApp Is Nothing Then objWordApp = Nothing
            'exit application with exit code 0 (successful)
            ' Environment.Exit(0)
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
```

Similar results can be found using the `.ScaleWidth` and `.ScaleHeight` methods.  The proper location for the documentation for the aforementioned methods are https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape.

In the end I used the code above as I got more reliable results with size, which ran the reduced risk of any over\underlapping.